# How to emit sound using built-in speaker from a command line?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, audio, speakers

How to emit sound using built-in speaker from a command line in Windows and Linux?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the Win32 MessageBeep operating system function.

On Windows XP or later, type:

```
rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep
```

I tried it years ago and at first I didn't believe it would work. But that's Microsoft suggested way, as according to their MSDN website:

> "...MessageBeep attempts to play the
>   system default sound. If it cannot
>   play the system default sound, the
>   function produces a standard beep
>   sound through the computer speaker."

Comment: If this is the approved answer, BOY Linux is a pale shadow of its predacessors: In about 1991, I think it was, a colleague did "cat toilet_flus.wav > /dev/sound on my brand new Sun SparcStation II, and, as I was on the phone with a customer, the customer remarked, "BOY, they sure don't give you guys a break, do they?!"  Yuck Yuck... It's so hard on Linux? Pity.

Answer (score 4):

On *nix operating systems [beep](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/utils/beep.html) used to do it.

> SYNOPSIS
>
> `beep [ -v ] [ -X | -T | -S ]`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> beep is a command-line utility for making a computer go beep.
>
> Under normal circumstances, you should be able to use it just by typing ‘beep’, with no options.

Comment: What operating systems were these?

Comment: You can install this from most debian based linux repositories with sudo apt-get install beep

Comment: required `modprobe pcspkr` too, http://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working

Answer (score 1):

With bash on Unix:

```
echo $'\007'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Echo ^g
```

where ^ is the ctrl key.  Note this doesn't work on Windows 7 - The beep is redirected to the audio system.

Comment: hey, it works on Windows 7!!!! I think for some motherboards that does not have internal speaker or that it is disabled on sound properties it will not beep. but I tested and functioned!!! but use CTRL instead of "^" character. I don't know the difference, but...

Comment: The difference is that "^" character is ASCII 94, & the bell character is ASCII 7. [CTRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) is a modifier key, to generate non printable ASCII characters from a keyboard (104 keys) that doesn't have a separate key for every ASCII character (255)